# how to refine search with mysql and php based on different filter parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an e-commerce site . I would like to allow the user to refine the search results similar to myntra.com or other commercial website.

So i have three main ways to search results:

Price
Color
Category

Currently I am using 3 different queries for each way. Problem is to bind the result of one search to another.

Comment: You should add more information to the question, like the queries you are doing and the table structure. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Maybe you could do it with javascript. Do you know DataTables? http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: i am showing you sql query to search by color

Comment: $sql = "SELECT  * FROM internet_shop where color ='".$filterByColor."'";

Comment: no i don'ty know about data tables, please let me know the method